# convert multiline rsult from mysql into one row

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table
userRoleTable, having some column

```
userName, rollId
pramod    1
shakti    2
vijay     2
mahesh    2
raja      1
vipul     3
raman     1
sachin    3
```

I want to write a select query, so i get the result in one row.

```
pramod, raja, raman
```

Please suggest me some possible solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(userName) AS result FROM userRoleTable WHERE rollId ='1';
```

It will give comma separated values in one column

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(userName) AS usename FROM userRoleTable WHERE rollId ='1'
```

> The GROUP_CONCAT function concatenates strings from a group into one
>   string with various options